# Multiply two matrices with different dimensions python

Tags: python, matrix

Error: `ValueError: shapes (3,1) and (3,2) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0)`

The error occurs because the matrices are different sizes, but how can I multiply two matrices with different size and where the resulting output should be: `[-0.78 0.85]`?

```
import numpy as np

x1 = 3-7/3;
x2 = 2-4/3;
x3 = 1-5/3;

X = ([x1], [x2],[x3])

V = ([-0.99, -0.13], [-0.09, 0.70],[0.09, -0.70])

res = np.dot(X,V)
print("Res: ",res)
```

Any help is appreciated!

---

**Mathematical question, for better understanding:**

A principal component analysis is carried out on a dataset comprised of three data points x1, x2 and x3 collected in a N × M matrix **X** such that each row of the matrix is a data point. Suppose the matrix X ̃ corresponds to **X** with the mean of each columns substracted i.e.

**X** = ([3.00, 2.00, 1.00],[4.00, 1.00, 2.00],[0.00, 1.00, 2.00])

and suppose X ̃ has the singular value decomposition:

**V** = ([-0.99, -0.13, -0.00], [-0.09, 0.70, -0.71],[0.09, -0.70, -0.71])

What is the (rounded to two significant digits) coordinates of the first observation x1 projected onto the 2-Dimensional subspace containing the maximal variation?

**Answer:**

The projection can be found by substracting the mean from **X**
and projecting onto the first two columns of **V**. The first point with the mean subtracted has coordinates: [2-7/3 2-4/3 1-5/3]

This should be (left) multiplied with the first two columns of **V**:

([3-7/3], [2-4/3],[1-5/3]) * ([-0.99, -0.13], [-0.09, 0.70],[0.09, -0.70]) = [-0.78 0.85]

---

So I am trying to find out how to calculate this in python.

Comment: Explain, why should it be `[-0.78 0.85]`

Comment: How do you multiply a 3×1 matrix with a 3×2 matrix? It's simply not a possibly operation in math!

Comment: X needs to be a (1x3) vector instead of a (3x1) vector to make the dot product possible. `X = ([x1, x2, x3])`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP expects numpy to do something mathematically impossible.

Comment: @sudden_appearance I have added mathematical question for why it should be `[-0.78 0.85]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you wish to perform matrix multliplication. This cannot be achieved if the dimensions of the matrices are different. You can achieve the desired result by using `reshape` and `numpy.matmul()`.
Code:

```
import numpy as np

x1 = 3-7/3;
x2 = 2-4/3;
x3 = 1-5/3;

X = np.array([[x1], [x2],[x3]])
X = X.reshape(1, 3)

V = np.array([[-0.99, -0.13], [-0.09, 0.70],[0.09, -0.70]])

res = np.matmul(X, V)
print("Res: ",res)
```

Comment: You can directly create the array with the correct shape instead of reshaping it. and you might want to use `.dot` instead of `matmul` (for this problem both work though)

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Thank you for the suggestion, yes we could but in future references, where the data is large it might not be possible. Hence I used reshape :)